# Randomize an array with dependent arrays and then have them post to html

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, random

I would like for the javascript to have a random array for an audio file which is then placed into the audio controls tag in html. Then, depending on which audio file was picked, another randomized array will begin to place an image into a div and so on and so forth.

Also here is the website in question: http://driglight.com/Learn5.html
This website does not currently have randomization implemented.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
<title>Learn</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom-styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/component.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome-ie7.css">

   <script src="js/Timhasnoinput.js"></script>
    <!-- <script  src="js/stuff.js"></script> -->
</head>
<body>
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>
        <p class="chromeframe">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> or <a href="http://www.google.com/chromeframe/?redirect=true">activate Google Chrome Frame</a> to improve your experience.</p>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- This code is taken from http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/hero.html -->
        <div class="header-wrapper">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row-fluid">

                    <div class="site-name">
                        <h1>Music Website</h1>
                    </div>




                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
        <div class="menu">

                    <div class="navbar">
                        <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                            <i class="fw-icon-th-list"></i>
                        </a>
                        <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                            <ul class="nav">
                                <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>


                                <li><a href="Learn.html">Learn</a></li>
                                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
                    </div>
                    <div class="mini-menu">
        <label>
      <select class="selectnav">
        <option value="#" selected="">Home</option>

        <option value="#">→ Hello</option>
        <option value="#">→ Something else here</option>
        <option value="#">→ Another action</option>
        <option value="#">→ Something else here</option>
        <option value="#">About</option>
        <option value="#">Learn</option>
        <option value="#">Contact</option>
      </select>
      </label>
      </div>

        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container bg-white">
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span12 ">
                    <div class="main-caption">
                        <h1>Music Website</h1>
                        <h6>Learning Music</h6>

                    </div>
                    <div class="Timmy2">
                                    <h4><a href="Learn4.html">< Lesson 2</a></h4>
                                    <h6></h6>
                                  </div>
                </div>
             </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container bg-white">

            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span12">
                    <div class="banner">
                    <div class="audiobuttonholder">
                    <div class="audioholder" style="padding-bottom:24px;">
                      <audio controls>
                      <source src= audio_1 type="audio/mpeg">

                        hello
                        </audio> 
                        </div>
                        <div class="buttonholder"; style="position: absolute; left: 10px; top: 40px;"> 

                        </div>
                    <div class = "numberPage">
                    Pg. 3 Trebble Cleff
                    </div>
                        <div class = "control">





                        <ul>  
 <div id="div1"  style="display:none; float: right; margin-right: 120px; 
margin-top: 40px;"  > 

 </div>
 <input type="image" id="myimage1" style="height:200px;width:200px;"   
onclick="showDivOne()"/> 

 </ul>

                        <ul>
<div id="div2"  style="display:none; float: right; margin-right: 120px;" > 

 </div>
<input type="image" id="myimage2" style="height:200px;width:200px; padding-
top:24px;" onclick="showDivTwo()"/>
</ul>

<ul>
<div id="div3"  style="display:none; float: right; margin-right: 120px; 
padding-top: 40px;" > 

</div>
<input type="image" id="myimage3" style="height:200px;width:200px;
paddingtop:24px;" onclick="showDivThree()"/>
</ul>




 <ul> 
 <div id="div4"  style="display:none; float: right; margin-right: 120px; 
margin-
top: 40px;" > 

 </div>
 <input type="image" id="myimage4" style="height:200px;width:200px;" 
onclick="showDivFour()" />
 </ul>



 <!--
 <div id="welcomeDiv"  style="display:none;" > <input type="image" 
id="myimage" style="height:150px;width:400px;" src="Continue.png" /></div>
<input type="image" name="answer" src="Continue.png" onclick="showDiv()" /> 
-->


<!--
 <div id="welcomeDiv"  style="display:none;" > 
 <img src = "GoodJob.png"></img>
 </div>
<input type="image" id = "HaveFun" style="height:200px;width:200px;" src = 
"HighE.gif" onclick="showDiv()" />
 -->




                        </div>
            </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

                       <div class="featured-images">
                        <ul class="grid effect-8" id="grid">
                          <li>
                            <div class="block">
                             <div class="Timmy2">
                                    <h4><a href="Learn3.html">< Lesson 2</a>
</h4>
                                    <h6></h6>
                                  </div>
                            </div>
                          </li>
                        </ul>
                            <div class="block-content">

                                  <div class="user-info">

                                   <h4><a href="index.html">Home</a></h4>
                                   <h6> </h6>

                                   </div>

                                <div class="user-info">

                                    <h4><a href="Learn.html">Learn</a></h4>
                                    <h6> </h6>
                                </div>
                                <div class="user-info">

                                   <h4><a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
</h4>
                                   <h6> </h6>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>

            </div>
        </div>







    <script>

    function() {
    document.getElementById("audio1").innerHTML = rand_audio_1;
    var audio_1 = ["LowATrebbleCleffPianoVC.mp3"],
["LowETrebbleCleffPianoVC.mp3"],["LowGTrebbleCleffPianoVC.mp3"],
["MidBTrebbleCleffPianoVC.mp3"],["MidCTrebbleCleffPianoVC.mp3"],
["MidDTrebbleCleffPianoVC.mp3"];
    var rand_audio_1 = audio_1[Math.floor(Math.random()*audio_1.length)];
    }
    function() {

    if (audio_1[0]){
    document.getElementById("rand1").innerHTML =  "<img src='LowA.gif'>";
    var R1 = ["myimage1"],["myimage2"],["myimage3"],["myimage4"];
    var rand1 = R1[Math.floor(Math.random()* R1.length)];
    } else if(audio_1[1]){
    document.getElementById("rand1").innerHTML = "<img src='LowE.gif'>";
    var R1 = ["myimage1"],["myimage2"],["myimage3"],["myimage4"];
    var rand1 = R1[Math.floor(Math.random()* R1.length)];
    } else if(audio_1[2]){
    document.getElementById("rand1").innerHTML = "<img src='LowG.gif'>";
    var R1 = ["myimage1"],["myimage2"],["myimage3"],["myimage4"];
    var rand1 = R1[Math.floor(Math.random()* R1.length)];
    } else if(audio_1[3]){
    document.getElementById("rand1").innerHTML = "<img src='MidB.gif'>";
    var R1 = ["myimage1"],["myimage2"],["myimage3"],["myimage4"];
    var rand1 = R1[Math.floor(Math.random()* R1.length)];       
    } else if(audio_1[4]){
    document.getElementById("rand1").innerHTML = "<img src='MidC.gif'>";
    var R1 = ["myimage1"],["myimage2"],["myimage3"],["myimage4"];
    var rand1 = R1[Math.floor(Math.random()* R1.length)];
    } else {
    document.getElementById("rand1").innerHTML = "<img src='MidD.gif'>";
    var R1 = ["myimage1"],["myimage2"],["myimage3"],["myimage4"];
    var rand1 = R1[Math.floor(Math.random()* R1.length)];
    }
    }

    function() {
    if (R1[0]) {
    document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML = "<img src='GoodJob.png'>";
    } else if(R1[1]) {
    document.getElementById('div2').innerHTML = "<img src='GoodJob.png'>";
    } else if(R1[2]){
    document.getElementById('div3').innerHTML = "<img src='GoodJob.png'>";
    } else if(R1[3]) {
    document.getElementById('div4').innerHTML = "<img src='GoodJob.png'>";
    } else {
    document.getElementById('div5').innerHTML = "<img src='GoodJob.png'>";
   }
   }
   }
</body>
```

Comment: Nice plan! Let me know if you get stuck somewhere.

Comment: Please don't regurgitate your entire code onto Stack Overflow. Create a [mcve]; meaning, narrow your code down to the problem you are facing. There are many, many questions about how to randomize/shuffle arrays in JavaScript and how to get random items from them. Read those, apply the code, then if you have questions, come back and ask about those specific problems.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does work. In a way. Some errors:

```
function(){  .... }
```

Will do nothing. Functions are there to be executed! (you never do this)

```
var arr=["a"],["b"];
```

arr will be an array with "a" and "b" right? Nope! Youve missmatched the brackets, now theyre actually two arrays, evaluated with the comma operator:

```
console.log(arr);//["b"]
```

So you want to do:

```
var arr=["a","b"];
```

Arrays are made to make things easier, not to then do a lot of if elses. So at first, we want to generate random audios, then take some possible images out of the images_per_audio array, and take a random one of them:

```
window.onload=function(){
   var audio_holder=document.getElementById("audio1"),
        image_holder=document.getElementById("rand1");

var audios= ["LowATrebbleCleffPianoVC.mp3","LowETrebbleCleffPianoVC.mp3","LowGTrebbleCleffPianoVC.mp3","MidBTrebbleCleffPianoVC.mp3","MidCTrebbleCleffPianoVC.mp3","MidDTrebbleCleffPianoVC.mp3"];

var images_per_audio = [
   ["myimage1","myimage2","myimage3","myimage4"],
   ["myimage1","myimage2","myimage3","myimage4"],
   ["myimage1","myimage2","myimage3","myimage4"],
   ["myimage1","myimage2","myimage3","myimage4"],
   ["myimage1","myimage2","myimage3","myimage4"],
   ["myimage1","myimage2","myimage3","myimage4"]
];

if(images_per_audio.length!==audios.length) throw new Error("Images and Audios do not match!");

var audio_index = Math.floor(Math.random()*audios.length);

var audio=audios[audio_index];
var images=images_per_audio[audio_index];
var image=images[Math.floor(Math.random()*images.length)];

audio_holder.innerHTML="<audio src='"+audio+"'>";
image_holder.innerHTML="<img src='"+image+".jpg'>";

};
```

Comment: I'm not sure if the code works yet, but your explanation is very helpful! Thank you very much for your time and effort! :)

Comment: Also, myimage1 and ect... aren't images themselves, they are id's to divs which will hold the images. I had made an array where the id's were randomized so the image would be placed in a random div. Because let's say LowTrebbleCleffPianoVC.mp3 got picked through the randomization, then I would want an array that has .document.innerHTML with the image source being "LowA.gif" to match the audio chosen and the randomization to be of the div id's called myimage1, myimage2 and so on... so that way the image LowA.gif was placed randomly in one of these.

Comment: @DrigDramel i think you can change that yourself. Ive already provided a good startingpoint...

Comment: Okay. thank you very much for you help. It doesn't make a lot of sense to me right now, but I am sure over time I will figure it out :)

Comment: var audio=audios[audio_index]; I am confused by this, specifically what the brackets around the second variable do. audios[audio_index] This part I don't know how to read.

Comment: @drig dramel the bracket nitation is an essential part of js. I think you should have have a deeper look into it...

Comment: This is my first project using js. I'm doing it as a hobby so I'm learning as I go.Thank you for telling me that it's called a bracket notation. I was able to look it up and learn more about it.